Text of the Dead Sea Scrolls in the original language(s)
I have found plenty of English translations of the Dead Sea Scrolls but never the original Hebrew/Greek/Aramaic texts. There are pictures of the findings online, but not the text itself in textual form. If there are English translations, then the original text is somewhere. Do you know any books and/or websites where I can find what I'm looking for?
Thanks in advance!
In Christ,
George

this might help https://zenodo.org/records/3737950#.XrQIeqhvaUl

Have you looked at Gallery in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dead_Sea_Scrolls#:~:text=Most%20of%20the%20manuscripts%20are%20written%20in%20Hebrew%2C,%28from%20Masada%29%20and%20Arabic%20%28from%20Khirbet%20al-Mird%29.%20

The OP pitches the question in a way that feels on my level, so I'd recommend:-
The Dead Sea scrolls : Hebrew, Aramaic, and Greek texts with English translations - Charlesworth (Princeton University, 1994)
Two volumes of it are currently on archive.org, out of I think eight
This only includes the non-biblical scrolls. Tracking down a full set outside of a university might be expensive, or need a copyright-library.
==
For scans of the scrolls there is:-
https://www.deadseascrolls.org.il/explore-the-archive
This does include the biblical ones.
===
Which leaves a sizeable subset of scrolls that are biblical but not easy to find transcribed without a subscription service. (apparently there is https://scholarlyeditions.brill.com/dsbo/ )
Some of the big and important and intact and famous biblical scrolls are online at http://dss.collections.imj.org.il/isaiah
[humour] There can't be very much demand in the market for an edition of three-inch-square bible fragments that (if the Isaiah scroll is anything to go by) are very similar to what we already had. "Scrolls" was an upbeat title - papyrology waking up to modern PR. "The Dead Sea Jarful-o-Bits" wouldn't have had the same ring to it.
